# Using Jenkins, how can a cascade of builds be triggered?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Using Jenkins, I am trying to arrange for the success of one build to trigger another build, so that there will be a cascade of builds until failure.

Given three projects (project1, project2, and project3), I am using Parameterized Trigger Plugin. How should I write the condition in the "Predefined parameters" field.

For example:

```
project1->success then trigger project2->success then trigger project3
```

In Jenkins I configure freestyle job.

Answer (score 3):

Use a wrapper job of **MultiJob** type:

> https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

This will enable you to put each of your projects as a phase in the build and build the logic you need and much more

Answer (score 2):

Look for the "Trigger when build is" Stable
[image: Example]